# nopcommerce Nop.Web refused the apply because of mime type

Tags: c#, nopcommerce, wwwroot

Steps

- Download package with source code from nopcommerce website [link](https://www.nopcommerce.com/en/download-nopcommerce)
- Try to start the project and get error because global.json file sdk version doesn't match my local sdk
- Delete the global.json file
- Start Nop.Web from visual studio by clicking the start button at the top that says IIS
- Connect local db
- Get this error on the console and have an ugly website:

Refused to apply style from 'https://localhost:44369/css/0ikql5uuycog9tlc6sjulg.styles.css?v=-q8BQzej0pnv8-fxjP5Ge9M9qh4' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

I looked online and I think I need to give some permissions to IIS so it can access the files but I don't know how to do that?

So, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why delete global.json?

Comment: Because, it is non-trivial for me to install a software because of company restrictions and I saw a stackoverflow answer that suggested it. I don't think it is the cause of my problems.